# Replacing decimal point with an operator in a float value and output the result. php

Tags: php

I have a weird question here. How can I do this.
So I have a decimal number 1.2; I would like to replace the decimal point with an add sign so that it would be 1+2 and output the value which is 3.

This is what I have tried so far.
replace the dot using `str_replace`

```
<?php
    $a = 1.2; 

    $added_decimal = str_replace('.','+',$a);

    echo $added_decimal;
```

The above code outputs 1+2, so it does not compute it.

I also tried converting the decimal to an array like so;

```
<?php
$a = 1 .'.'. 2; //Concatenated it

explode('.',$a); //entered the delimeter

echo $a[0] + $a[2]; //this outputs 3;
```

So this one works fine, but then the problem would be when `$a` was `1.20`. This would also output 3 if my code above was use. How would I go about getting 1+ 20 and output 21?

Comment: For one thing `1.20` IS `1.2` if you store it as a number.

Comment: To keep the trailing zeroes, assign as a string: `$a = '1.20';` instead of `$a = 1.20;`.

Answer (score 2):

Your second code snippet is almost correct. You just need to store the explode() result in a variable. See this code snippet :

```
<?php
$a = 1 .'.'. 20; //Concatenated it

$x = explode('.',$a); //entered the delimeter

echo $x[0] + $x[1]; //this outputs 21;
```

When you do $a[0], you actually access the index of the string not the explode() result.